# Adobe AIR app gives error 2032 on HTTP request(403)

Tags: flash, proxy, air, adobe

I have a adobe AIR project which gives me the error code (2032) for a HTTP request. The HTTP request returns an error code of 403.

What could be the possible reasons why this is the case

I suspect this might have something to do with my proxy settings

Comment: Use the [edit option](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64690227/edit) to update your question. Not enough info to answer this as a **programming** problem. Does it work with requests to other servers? Does it work if the request is to an HTTPS end-point? If still unsure.. Finally tell us how to reproduce your problem (show a function code to do some request to a test file on your server that causes this 403 issue). Something we can test to find a solution.

Comment: "The **HTTP 403** is a **HTTP** status code meaning access to the requested resource is forbidden for some reason." Meaning, your client is not authorized (possible reason: you have not performed HTTP authorization routine) to perform the request.

Comment: Question is unclear